# Provide an example of a Banach space $X$ and a functional $f$ in $X'$ such that there is no unit norm vector $x$ in $X$ satisfying $|f|=f(x)$

Tags: functional-analysis

Give an example of a Banach space $X$ and a functional $f$ in $X'$ such that there is no unit norm vector $x$ in $X$ satisfying $|f|=f(x)$.

Comment: does the functional go to R or C?

Comment: Either one R or C